# CentOS - Why is NY/EST Timezone being considered MST?

Tags: linux, centos, timezone

It seems as if the server thinks New York is MST, despite all my efforts of trying to set it to EST. Just what is going on here? The time in New York is actually 2:22PM EST, but my server is stuck 3 hours beforehand. I thought maybe the zoneinfo files were outdated, so I ran yum update tzdata, but there was nothing to update.

Here is my time setup:

**After copying EST file zone**

```
# rm /etc/localtime; cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/EST /etc/localtime
```

Also tried

```
# rm /etc/localtime; cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern /etc/localtime
```

And

```
# rm /etc/localtime; cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
```

**I set the system clock**

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
ZONE="America/New_York"
UTC=false
ARC=false
```

**I run tzselect**

```
Therefore TZ='America/New_York' will be used.
Local time is now:      Fri Sep 27 11:22:56 MST 2013.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Sep 27 18:22:56 UTC 2013.
Is the above information OK?
1) Yes
2) No
#? (canceled)
```

**Run ntpdate**

```
# ntpdate 0.centos.pool.ntp.org
adjust time server 199.30.140.74 offset 0.006327 sec
```

**The system time isn't correct:**

```
# date
Fri Sep 27 11:22:31 MST 2013
```

**Hardware clock reflects the incorrect system time:**

```
# hwclock --show
Fri 27 Sep 2013 11:22:37 AM MST  -0.297177 seconds
```

**Apache time is also wrong:**

```
09/27/2013 11:22:26am [America/New_York]
```

**Code:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$z = date_default_timezone_get();
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:sa') . " [{$z}]";
```

Comment: Just a side note, don't copy the zoneinfo files, link them instead.

Comment: MST isn't even in use at this time of year.. PDT is currently -7, though.  Seems like something's very wrong with your `America/New_York`, if you're getting `Therefore TZ='America/New_York' will be used.` then `Local time is now:      Fri Sep 27 11:22:56 MST 2013.`

Comment: @ShaneMadden It is in Arizona.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Arizona doesn't count! ;)